# Как найти слово из одной буквы в строке?

Tags: javascript

Задача, преобразовать строку в объект вида:

- имя свойства - слово из строки,
- значение свойства - количество вхождений в строку.

Написал функцию:

```
function countWords(str) {
  var arr = str.split(' ');
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   var word = arr[i];
   obj[word] = str.split(word).length - 1;
  }
    return obj;
}

console.log(countWords('ask a bunch get a bunch')); 

// Результат --> {ask: 1, a: 3, bunch: 2, get: 1}
// Ожидаемый результат --> {ask: 1, a: 2, bunch: 2, get: 1}
```

Как добиться, чтобы 'a' из слова 'ask' не считалась вхождением слова 'a'?

Пытался регулярными выражениями, но не понимаю, как приделать '\b' к переменной word в split(word).

Comment: а `obj[word]++` вы просто делать не можете потому что...?

Comment: @teran, потому что undefined.

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо кэп! :) я вообще про подход, а не про конкретику :)

Comment: А /\s[...]\s/ не прокатит?

Comment: @teran, даже в голову не пришло. мой уровень - самый начальный. спасибо за науку!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя более элегантный способ уже и приведен в [ответе @Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/714374/223826) оставлю этот код как один вариантов.

```js
function countWords(str) {
    var arr = str.split(' ');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var word = arr[i];

        if( !obj[word]) obj[word] = 1
        else obj[word]++;    
    }
    return obj;
}

console.log(countWords('ask a bunch get a bunch'));
```

*`var obj = {}` следует заменить на `Object.create(null)`, как написано в комментариях.*

Comment: Запусти на строке из моего ответа и обрати внимание на `toString: NaN`. У меня там от этого в двух местах защита - `Object.create(null)` и `~~` - т. е. даже если изначально поставить `{}`, то `~~` всё равно превратит мусор в 0. Ну а больше 2 млн слов всё равно никто не даст :)

Comment: @Qwertiy да, `toString` видел

Comment: Другой вариант `!obj[word]` заменить на `!obj.hasOwnProperty(word)` - будет несколько дружелюбнее для иешек старых))

Comment: @teran, спасибо, ваш ответ мне понятнее - его я хотя бы смогу повторить при случае.Чтобы усвоить ответ Qwertiy, мне еще нужно подучиться.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function count(s) {
  var a = s.split(/[^a-zа-яё]+/ig).filter(Boolean)
  var res = Object.create(null)
  
  for (var q=0; q<a.length; ++q) {
    res[a[q]] = ~~res[a[q]] + 1
  }
  
  return res
}

console.log(count("Just a test with toString and русский текст, test again and текст again!"))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh; }
```

Что тут интересного:

- разделителями считается всё кроме русских и латинских букв
- `.filter(Boolean)` отсеивает пустые строки в случае, если в начале или конце строки стояли разделители
- `Object.create(null)` создаёт чистый объект, у которого в прототипе нет ничего, в том числе методов как toString
- `~~res[a[q]]` приводит нечисловой мусор в 0 - в данном случае надо для undefined, но если заменить `Object.create(null)` на `{}`, то поможет ещё и с `toString`, т. к. это не число. Из минусов - ограничение в 2<sup>31</sup>-1, но столько слов в строке не будет.

Comment: `~~res[a[q]] + 1` - что это (~~) за магия?

Comment: @MedvedevDev https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971645/1216425

Comment: @teran, благодарю.

Comment: @MedvedevDev, немного дополнил.